# Ionic Cordova Webpage not available after run

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, webview, sdk

Trying to add support for 13, 14 android on the app. Updated cordova, ionic. The application is build without errors. After launching it the following message appears: Webpage not available

Trying on 34 SDK

Updated webview to the latest version, but it's still the same
https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#requirements

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/android": "^1.5.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "1.5.1",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^1.5.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": ">=5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^5.29.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": ">=5.22.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": ">=5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-selectable/angular": "^5.0.0-alpha.13",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angular8-yandex-maps": "^1.11.0",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.4",
    "cookiefile": "^1.0.10",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-app-preferences": "git+https://github.com/vash15/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences.git",
    "cordova-plugin-cookies": "0.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-opentok": "^3.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-sync-cookies": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-system": "^2.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic2-zoom-area": "^1.0.16",
    "ionic4-auto-complete": "^2.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "req-fast": "^0.2.21",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "8.4.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.23",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@capacitor/cli": "1.5.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^12.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "ANDROIDBLACKLISTSECURESOCKETPROTOCOLS": "SSLv3,TLSv1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-cookies": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]